# How To Display A Value from ng-options values in separate div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code. Whenever I display the ng-option values in a separate div it is displaying the linkToken instead of the Name. Either that or if I assign a static value from the array (ie. [0].Name) it does not change when I change between the dropdown values. How can I return the Name from the ng-options onchange instead of linkToken. I only need to display to client, I still need to pass linktoken to the rest of the function. Thanks

```
<select class="report-user"
    ng-change="userChange(refillDropUser)"
    ng-model="refillDropUser"
    ng-options="value.LinkToken as value.Name for value in refillUsers"
    options-class="{{Dependants.DependantClass}}"
    required></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `LinkToken` becuase you set value field `LinkToken` in `ngOptions`

```
ng-options="value.LinkToken as value.Name for value in refillUsers" options-class="{{Dependants.DependantClass}}"
```

Try like this

```
ng-options="value as value.Name for value in refillUsers" options-class="{{Dependants.DependantClass}}"
```

JS

```
$scope.userChange=function(refillDropUser){
  console.log(refillDropUser.name)
}
```

Comment: You can omit the `value as` entirely

Comment: Will this allow me to continue to pass the linkToken? I have to pass linkToken from the selected user to other functions to call specific data for the selected user.

Comment: This will return selected object where you can any property of selected object @billy_comic

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After altering code on change the getUserInfo function fails due to no link token. I need then both in the options. I have the name returning to the drop down and the link token passes through to function. Just having problems displaying the name from drop down in a different location on display after change.

Comment: can you provide your updated code or jsfiddle will be better ? @billy_comic

Comment: I will have to set up a mock as the code in this service, controller, and view is fairly large. Thanks for the eyes.